# Rails Form Association Field Shows Object Instead of Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, haml, simple-form

I have a form that edits an object with an association, but the select menu shows the associated object instead of the user-friendly name (i.e. `#<User:0x007fdcac6da278>` instead of `SeanPerryman`). How can I set the value for that association box to be a value associated with that object?

```
= simple_form_for(@captain) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.association :user 
  = f.input :name
  = f.association :world
  = f.button :submit
```

Looks like it is doing it for the World association, but not for the User association.

[image]

I've tried adding a value tag:

```
= f.association :user, :value => @captain.user.username
```

But that doesn't change the display, and inspecting the select box has no mention of the value tag that I added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use simple_form's `label_method` option, like this:

```
f.association :user, label_method: :username
```

See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations